# need help on coding for search using area, file no, applicant and application status

Tags: php

i have an application in office used for registration of project application. it was developed using code igniter framework for MVC. The application can be used to search file based on the area and application status only. However there are 4 search item which is area, file no., applicants, and application status. Now i want to do search using area and file no. or applicant name. below is the existing codes:

MODEL CODES

```
    > public function hasilCarianPermohonan()
{
    $mukim_id = $_POST['mukim_id'];
    $no_fail = $_POST['no_fail'];
    $pemohon = $_POST['pemohon'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    if($pemohon == NULL)
    {
        $pemohon = "%";
    } else if($no_fail == NULL)
    {
        $no_fail = "%";
    }

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM permohonan pr INNER JOIN    
status_permohonan st ON pr.no_fail = st.no_fail WHERE pr.mukim_id LIKE  '$mukim_id' AND st.status LIKE '$status' AND (pr.no_fail LIKE '$no_fail' OR pr.pemohon LIKE '$pemohon') ORDER BY pr.app_id ASC");

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

CONTROLLER CODES

```
    public function carian()
{

    /*

    This function is used to allow the user to search the database record for any one of the matching criteria 
    of the application including the mukim, file holding person, status and etc.

    */

    $data['mukim_id'] = 0; // default selectbox index
    $data['status'] = "0"; // default selectbox status

    $data['isResult'] = false;  
    $this->load->view('view-carian',$data);
}

public function hasilcarian()
{
    /*

    Render a record found view for the carian function.

    */


    $data['mukim_id'] = $_POST['mukim_id']; /*'mukim_id is area */
    $data['status'] = $_POST['status'];     /*'status is application status. i want to add 'no_fail' (file no.) and 'pemohon'(applicant) so i can search file using these from database */
    $data['isResult'] = true;

    $data['list'] = $this->modelpermohonan->hasilCarianPermohonan();

    if($data['list'] == false)
    {
        $data['isResult'] = false;
        $this->session->set_flashdata('mesej', '<span class="label label-info">Tiada rekod yang sepadan dijumpai!</span> ');
    }

    $this->load->view('view-carian',$data);

}
```

VIEW CODES

```
    <?php echo $this->navigasi->top(); ?>

<div class="container">
    <br>
    <h4 style="margin:0 auto;width:650px;color:white;">Carian Permohonan</h4>
    <br>
    <form class="form-horizontal the-form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>permohonan/hasilcarian/" method="post">
      <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Mukim:</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <select name="mukim_id" class="span3" id="mukim_id">
                <option value="%" <?php if($mukim_id == 0) { echo "selected"; } ?>>-- Semua Mukim --</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if($mukim_id == 1) { echo "selected"; } ?>>Hulu Langat</option>
                <option value="2" <?php if($mukim_id == 2) { echo "selected"; } ?> >Kajang</option>
                <option value="3" <?php if($mukim_id == 3) { echo "selected"; } ?>>Cheras</option>
                <option value="4" <?php if($mukim_id == 4) { echo "selected"; } ?>>Beranang</option>
                <option value="5" <?php if($mukim_id == 5) { echo "selected"; } ?>>Semenyih</option>
                <option value="6" <?php if($mukim_id == 6) { echo "selected"; } ?>>Hulu Semenyih</option>

              </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">No. Fail Jabatan:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input name="no_fail" type="text" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="No. Fail Jabatan" id="no_fail">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Nama Pemohon:</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input name="pemohon" type="text" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Nama Pemohon" id="pemohon">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Status:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select name="status" class="span3" id="status">
                  <option value="%" <?php if($status == 0) { echo "selected"; } ?>>-- Semua Status --</option>
                  <option value="Dalam Proses"  <?php if($status == "Dalam Proses") { echo "selected"; } ?>>Dalam Proses</option>
                  <option value="Lulus" <?php if($status == "Lulus") { echo "selected"; } ?>>Lulus</option>
                  <option value="Tangguh" <?php if($status == "Tangguh") { echo "selected"; } ?>>Tangguh</option>
                  <option value="Tolak" <?php if($status == "Tolak") { echo "selected"; } ?>>Tolak</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label"></label>
            <div class="controls">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Cari Rekod</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br><br>

    <!-- Keputusan Carian !-->
    <center><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('mesej'); ?></center>
    <?php if($isResult == true) { ?>

    <table class="table table-bordered" style="background:#fff;">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Bil.</th>
              <th>No. Fail</th>
              <th>Pemohon</th>
              <th>Alamat Premis</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php $i = 1; foreach($list as $a) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $i; ?>.</td>
              <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>maklumat/<?php echo $a->app_id; ?>"><?php echo $a->no_fail; ?></a></td>
              <td><?php echo $a->pemohon; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $a->alamat_premis; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $a->status; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php $i++; } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>

      <?php } ?>
      <!-- Keputusan Carian !-->

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the MVC framework id made so that that your code is flexbile enough for a big app.

You have to write another model and another controller that generates a list for your view. That is the idea.